# How to install bazel in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, bazel

I want to use bazel builder for some project in colab. But `!bazel` gives me
`/bin/bash: bazel: command not found`. I tried to install it with

```
BAZEL_VERSION = '0.20.0'

!wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/{BAZEL_VERSION}/bazel-{BAZEL_VERSION}-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

!chmod +x bazel-{BAZEL_VERSION}-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

# !export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin:/root/bin"
```

But it didn't help. How should I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these commands:

```sh
!apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg
!curl -fsSL https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor > bazel.gpg
!mv bazel.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
!echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
!apt update && apt install bazel
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```bash
!npm install -g @bazel/bazelisk
```

`npm` is already installed by default in Colab. I just tested the above code and it works fine. More info: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk